# Matching only a <tab> that is between two numbers

Tags: vim

How to match a tab only when it is between two numbers?

*Sample script*

```
209.65834   27.23204908
119.37987   15.03317082
74.240635   8.30561924
29.1014 0

931.8861    -100.00000
-16.03784   -8.30562
;   
_mirror 
l   

;   
29.1014 0
1028.10 0.00
n   
_spline 
935.4875    250
924.2026913 269.8820375
912.9178825 277.4506484
890.348265  287.3181854
```

(in the above script, the tabs are between the numbers, not the spaces) (blank lines are significant; there is nothing in them, but I can't lose them)

I wish to get a "," between the numbers. Tried with `:%s/\t/\,/` but that will touch the empty lines too, and the end of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
:%s/\(\d\)\t\(-\?\d\)/\1,\2/
```

`\d` matches any digit. `-?` means "an optional `-`. The pair of (escaped) parenthesis capture the match, and `\1` refers to the first captured match, `\2` refers to the second.

Comment: It works. Would it be too much trouble to explain what *that thing* does? (\d is digit, equivalent to [0-9]) ?

Comment: Edited a bit. http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html has the basics. http://vimregex.com/ has vim-specific syntax and examples.

Comment: Yeah, know of them, along with a few other places. But I use regexes so rarely, that I mostly forget them between uses.

Comment: Just one more question. Why doesn't this match lines with negative numbers?

Comment: Because `\d` doesn't match `-`. Added an optional `-`.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\t\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/g
```

explanation -  search the patten `<digit>\t<digit>`  and remember the part that matches `<digit>` .
\( ...  \)  captures and remembers the part that matches.
\1  recalls the first captured digit, \2 the second captured digit.

so if the match was on  `123\t789`, `<digit>,<digit>` matches `3\t7`
  the 3 and 7 are rememberd as \1 and \2

or

```
:g/[0-9]/    s/\t/,/g
```

explanation - filter all lines with a digit,  then substitute tabs with a comma on those lines

Comment: It works. Would it be too much trouble to explain what *that thing* does?

Comment: Somewhat. I fugred it out (more or less). But, just to notice, that second line does not do the same thing as the first one. It also messes up the lines with text.

Comment: @Idigas, the second one is not exactly the same, in that  it will replace all tabs in any line that contains a digit.
the sample script has no case where there is a tab between words.
when the file does not contain tabs other than between numbers,  it would suffice.  Saves a bit of typing that way.  :)

Answer (score 1):

google://vim+regex -> http://vimregex.com/ ->

```
:%s/\([0-9]\)\t\([0-9]\)/\1,\2/gc
```

You have 2 groups of numbers here `([0-9])` and tab-symbols `\t` between them. Add some escape symbols and you have the answer.
`g` for multichange in single line, `c` for some asking.
`\1` and `\2` are matching groups (numbers in your case).

It's not really hard to find answer for questions like that by yourself.